# ¿Cómo hacer efecto borroso-transparente de los elementos que pasen detrás en CSS?

Tags: css, css3, estilos

Busco que los elementos `html` que pasen detrás de un `header`se muestren con efecto **transparente-borroso** cuando pasen detrás del `header`.

Intenté usar el `backdrop-filter: blur(5px);`, pero solo funciona el `opacity`.

Lo que busco es algo así:

El fondo detrás se ve transparente pero a la vez borroso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo único que me ha funcionado ha sido el `opacity`, aquí el ejemplo:

**Pero no se ve el efecto borroso**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo para el `header`:

```
.header {
padding: 5px 15px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99;
background: #ff4700;
border-radius: 0;
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);/*no hace efecto borroso*/
opacity: 0.90;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si colocas tu header dentro un div que tenga el `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)`? Así tendrías tu overlay con el opacity y un "blur transparente" detrás del div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade esta línea a tu clase .header, creo que es lo que te falta.

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

Te paso también un ejemplo para que lo puedas revisar.
Fuente: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/#browser-support

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://41.media.tumblr.com/efd15be8d41b12a7b0ef17fba27c3e20/tumblr_mqqy59HMaf1qzattso1_1280.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.modal {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="modal">
        <p>The background image should be pleasantly blurred under this box, <a href="https://i.imgur.com/z7s7uf6.png">like so</a>.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, quae distinctio magnam, laborum iusto itaque autem! Molestiae enim distinctio molestias, dolores ea quasi magni nisi aspernatur magnam, voluptate eum fuga.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```